# Extract domain from file name

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I am given one zip file which includes exactly 4 files with the following naming convention:

```
2018.foo.abc.example.co.uk.20183740273
2018.foo.bcd.example.co.uk.20183740474
2018.foo.dce.example.co.uk.20183749769
2018.foo.def.example.co.uk.20183746483
```

My task is to extract the domain from any filename (any, because all of the domains are the same) and store it into a bash variable. These file names are just examples. The key point is the domain. Split takes place after third dot.

Comment: Which part is the domain?

Comment: The domain is: example.co.uk. Sorry if I don’t make it clear enough in question

Comment: How do you determine where the domain ends?

Comment: That’s the tricky part, I can specify const array with all points of sales that I will allow. + I did try it, and it’s not a problem if you don’t help me, I can do it myself, I wanted opinion and help and not hate from the start, the attempt is in my office. I can’t access both files, laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract domains with different numbers of fields (e.g. `example.co.uk` and `example.com`) you can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([^.]*.\)\{3\}//;s/.[0-9]*$//' filename
```

or a combination of `sed` and `cut`, which is more readable:

```
sed 's/.[0-9]*$//' filename | cut -d '.' -f4-
```

Answer (score 3):

If the files are all named with the same convention, you can use some basic AWK to find the answer:

```
awk -F'.' 'print{$3,$4,$5}' <filename>
```

`-F` = field delimiter. In this case it is a `.`. Now that we have broken up the text into essentially columns of data, split on the `.`, we tell AWK which fields to print out.

Or you can use cut:

```
cut -d '.' -f3-5 <filename>
```

Same principle as AWK, just a different way to do it.

Comment: Or `< filename cut -d '.' -f3-6` (saves a cat).

Comment: Oh my. It actually worked like a dream, I will use <filename> + piped cut. Do you have any suggestions for different cases like .com and co.uk, the .com won’t give me correct value

Comment: @NarrowVision: if you want to handle such cases, you should say so in your question.

Comment: So, it is deliminating on the "." The x.x.com has only two ".", Which means there are essentially three columns (if you think of it like a spreadsheet). Where the x.x.co.uk  has three ".", Which has four columns if you think of it like a spreadsheet.
You just have to change the code to reflect the columns. You could add some regex, or a grep, or use SED. There are amillion ways to do it.  If that doesn't make sense I'll write a better explanation when I have time.

Comment: But @Beta has a better answer.  Always trust in SED for string manipulation.